# Javascript: change z-index onclick

Tags: javascript

I have seen questions similar to this one but not quite on point. I just want to do something really simple: when button 1 is clicked, it should hide and button 2 should appear; and then when button 2 is clicked, button 2 should hide and button 1 should show.
I am trying to do this by modifying the z-index, however it is not working.
This is the code I am using to do it:

```
if (attacker == player 1) {
    document.getElementById("p1-play").style.zIndex = -1;
    document.getElementById("p2-play").style.zIndex = 1;
}
else {
    document.getElementById(p2-play).style.zIndex = -1;
    document.getElementById(p1-play).style.zIndex = 1;
}
```

where p1-play is button 1 and p2-play is button 2

Comment: You'll notice the "" around the element id. I have tried with and without, but that does not make it work...

Comment: I would just use jQuery's .show(); and .hide(); functions. $("#p1-play").hide(); for example. When you hide one button show the other.

Comment: @user2649425 - Please don't suggest anyone should use jQuery just for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to use display:

```
var p1Play = document.getElementById("p1-play");
var p2Play = document.getElementById("p2-play");

if (attacker == player1) {
    p1Play.style.display = 'none';
    p2Play.style.display = 'block';
}
else {
    p1Play.style.display = 'block';
    p2Play.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: take out the space between player and 1

Comment: Damn it. This worked thanks a lot. There was a small mistake in your answer however: you set p1Play to 'none' in both cases... I am trying to show you the finished working code but I don't know how to insert code blocks...

Comment: I've edited the answer for you @HerrMann. If this is correct please accept this as the answer.